# Bitrix вывод счёта-фактуры в ЛК

Tags: битрикс

В админке битрикса у каждого заказа есть функция Печать документов. Как сделать подобную функцию для личного кабинета пользователя? Мне нужно вывести ссылку по заказу на счёт-фактуру, например. Кто - нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: смотрите ссылки как они генерируются как страница для печати, нет трудности сделать чтобы такое генерировалось для пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Вызовите в личном кабинете компонент со своим шаблон списка заказов
в этом шаблоне к элементу добавьте кнопку ведущую на адрес

[https://ваш_сайт.ru/bitrix/admin/sale_print.php?PROPS_ENABLE=Y&doc=factura&ORDER_ID=](https://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru/bitrix/admin/sale_print.php?PROPS_ENABLE=Y&doc=factura&ORDER_ID=)<сюда переменную с ID текущего заказа>&SHOW_ALL=Y

Comment: Интересный вариант, надеюсь безопасный. Тогда другой вопрос, можно ли содержимое этих документов, полностью, выдавать в пдф или ином формате? Важно не менять верстку документа. Естественно используя библиотеки mPdf или tcpdf и тому подобное. Интересует реальный опыт.

Comment: Также, этот вариант работает если у пользователя есть права. Так не пойдёт, увы. Но метод хороший.

Comment: В итоге сделал при помощи cURL, авторизовался, записал куки, и передал URL к документу. Выводит. Можно передавать любые GET запросы на любые документы. Вопрос с конвертацией в pdf остаётся открыт.

Comment: внутри вашего скрипта, который тянет курлом можно использовать любую подключаемую через composer либу, которая выполняет подобные задачи. (конвертирование в pdf)